# C++ Tree pointer issues

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-tree, deep-copy

I have an issue with binary search tree pointers and cannot determine the cause. I have a function in which I take two trees and exchange two subtrees of the trees at predetermined positions. This is the code that makes said exchange.

```
opNode* tmp = new opNode();
opNode* tmp2 = new opNode();
tmp = this->clone();
tmp2 = secondParentNode->clone();
this->operation = tmp2->operation;
this->val = tmp2->val;
this->lChild = tmp2->lChild;
this->rChild = tmp2->rChild;
secondParentNode = tmp;
```

At this point I have already determined the position of each subtree to be exchanged. The "this" pointer represents the first exchange point and secondParentNode is an opNode pointer that represents the second.

There are two issues here:

The first is that the exchange can create a situation in which a node has only one child. I have been unsuccessful in identifying how this is happening.

Second, and perhaps a relevant bit of information, once this->lChild is set to tmp2->lChild and this->rChild = tmp2->rChild, I had inserted a check as to whether secondParentNode->lChild or secondParentNode->rChild were null. This causes a segfault at least somewhat consistently.

Is the clone(deep copy) function not working? If so, why not? Any thoughts about what could be causing these issues would be appreciated.

opNode is my node class:

```
struct opNode
{
    string operation;
    double val;
    opNode* lChild;
    opNode* rChild;
    opNode* clone();
};
```

and the relevant clone function:

```
opNode* opNode::clone()
{
    if(this != nullptr)
    {
        opNode* n = new opNode();
        n->val = val;
        n->operation = operation;
        n->rChild = rChild->clone();
        n->lChild = lChild->clone();
        return n;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

EDIT* 
As requested, the exchange function. randPoint1 and randPoint2 are determined by taking a [uniform distribution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/):

```
uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, mate[k].root->count(0) - 1);
```

Where mate[k] is a root tree pointer and count is defined as:

```
int opNode::count(int c)
{
    if(this != nullptr)
    {
        c++;
        if(lChild != nullptr)
            c += lChild->count(0);
        if(rChild != nullptr)
            c += rChild->count(0);
        return c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The exchange function:

```
void opNode::recombination(opNode*& secondParentNode, int& randPoint1, int& randPoint2, bool& done)
{
    if(done)
        return;
    if(secondParentNode != nullptr && !done)
    {
        if(randPoint2 > 0 && secondParentNode->lChild != nullptr)
        {
            randPoint2--;
            recombination(secondParentNode->lChild, randPoint1, randPoint2, done);
        }

        if(randPoint2 > 0 && secondParentNode->rChild != nullptr)
        {
            randPoint2--;
            recombination(secondParentNode->rChild, randPoint1, randPoint2, done);
        }
    }
    if(this != nullptr && randPoint2 == 0 && !done)
    {
        if(randPoint1 > 0 && lChild != nullptr)
        {
            randPoint1--;
            lChild->recombination(secondParentNode, randPoint1, randPoint2, done);
        }
        if(randPoint1 > 0 && rChild != nullptr)
        {
            randPoint1--;
            rChild->recombination(secondParentNode, randPoint1, randPoint2, done);
        }
    }
    if(this != nullptr && secondParentNode != nullptr && randPoint1 == 0 && randPoint2 == 0 && !done)
    {
        opNode* tmp = new opNode();
        opNode* tmp2 = new opNode();
        tmp = this->clone();
        tmp2 = secondParentNode->clone();
        this->operation = tmp2->operation;
        this->val = tmp2->val;
        this->lChild = tmp2->lChild;
        this->rChild = tmp2->rChild;
        secondParentNode = tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an aside (I voted to close as you haven't provided a useful example), but your first code snippet is for some reason leaking two nodes. Also the "unreadable wall of text" is not a good look for questions.

Comment: What do you define as a useful example in this context?

Comment: While binary trees aren't the most complex data structure out there, it's fairly obvious from `tmp=new OpNode();... tmp =this-_clone()` or `this != nullptr` that you're still a beginner. Even if I were your colleague, I wouldn't start debugging this. The problem is that you wrote far too much code without testing.

Comment: I can't wait until I reach the next level where I'll ascend to saying tmp = clone() or if(this). Does unconventionality equate to a lack of knowledge? It's slightly more verbose. I have not worked much with data structures like this I've built myself, so in that regard you are correct. I also tested each function I needed to write individually and observed positive results. In this case, it goes to show the value of a thorough driver function, I suppose. Although, in this case I lack the knowledge to address this edge case so no driver I would write would help. Hence the question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the definition of a useful example. And sarcasm isn't a good look either. When MSalters points out that `if(this != nullptr)` is poor style, it isn't because you could be using `if(this)` instead, but because calling a method on a null object is invalid, so you've already invoked undefined behaviour before you reach the check. If it could be true, your code is already statically wrong. If it can't, you wrote extra logic that suggests you don't understand how your own code behaves.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that what I was doing causes undefined behavior, this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `rChild` or `lChild` are `nullptr`, then the calls `rChild->clone();` or `lChild->clone()` will cause segmentation fault.

We can rewrite the function as:

```
void opNode::clone(opNode* n)
{
    if (n)
    {
        n->val = val;
        n->operation = operation;
        if (rChild)
        {
            if (n->rChild)
            {
                 // release all right children.
            }
            n->rChild = new opNode;
            clone(n->rChild);
        }

        if (lChild)
        {
            if (n->lChild)
            {
                 // release all left children nodes.
            }
            n->lChild = new opNode;
            clone(n->lChild);
        }
    }
}
```

The code of exchange can be simplified as following:

```
opNode* tmp = new opNode;
clone(tmp);
secondParentNode->clone(this);
tmp->clone(secondParentNode);
```

Comment: I don't think that segfaulting on null children is the issue. I would successfully use the clone function previously. Unless this explains why the previous clone function could possibly define one child but not another, assuming a valid binary search tree as input. Additionally, this modified code causes a seperate segfault in malloc.c:3302.

Comment: Are the members `rChild` and `lChild` be initialized to `nullptr` when creating the `opNode`? When the members are initialized to `nullptr`, the code will segfaut immediately if the `opNode` has no left or right child.

Comment: That is incorrect. You can call a function of a null class pointer. I tested and this code works and produces expected results:                  opNode* n = new opNode();
    int a = n->lChild->count(0);
    a = 0;
    cout << a << endl;        And yes, opNode lChild and rChild are initialized to nullptr.

Comment: Can we know what input cause issue 1? Does the issue always occurred in this input or occasionally? Can you show the code segment that cause issue 2?

Comment: Issue 1: I am reasonably certain that this always occurs when swapping the root (the entire tree) of 2 trees of size 1 (each tree is a single node). I will update this with more information if I find any. Issue 2: `if((lChild == nullptr && rChild != nullptr) || (rChild == nullptr && lChild != nullptr) || (secondParentNode->rChild == nullptr && secondParentNode->lChild != nullptr) || (secondParentNode->lChild == nullptr && secondParentNode->rChild != nullptr))` I'm sorry I don't know how to better format this, but this if statement caused the crash.

Comment: We need to know the definition of the function `exchange` and the code segment of the use of `exchange`. I have tested the code in question and it works even for trees of size 1. The `if-condition` segfaults only when `secondParentNode` is `nullptr`. I'm not sure whether it is possible.

Comment: _"You can call a function of a null class pointer. I tested and this code works ..."_ Well, yes, one possible outcome of undefined behaviour is that it might work. At least some of the time, in some circumstances. It's still wrong though.

Comment: The code segment of exchanging tree nodes (the last `if`-condition) works fine except the leak issue (since the `tmp` and `tmp2` are replaced immediately by the function `clone` after `new`). You may need to trace the recursive call of `recombination`. Maybe print two trees in each call of `recombination`.

Comment: A couple changes allowed your original code to succeed, Kai. First, the recursive call to clone in the clone function should be `lChild->clone(n->lChild)` and for rChild as well. Additionally, simplifying the exchange the way you did caused the malloc issues. I had to revert to `opNode* tmp = new opNode;
opNode* tmp2 = new opNode;
clone(tmp);
secondParentNode->clone(tmp2);
val = tmp2->val;
operation = tmp2->operation;
lChild = tmp2->lChild;
rChild = tmp2->rChild;` I don't know why I had these issues either, but, regardless, thank you for your help and patience.